# Unable to install docker for windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install `docker` for `windows` in my `PC`, but unable to do that. The installation getting stuck at `"Removing Files.."` stage.

I am running the following commands in `PowerShell` to get the information of my OS

- `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Caption`

  **Microsoft Windows 10 Pro**
- `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | % Buildnumber`

  **15063**

[This picture showing virtualization is enabled in my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OAYa.png)

[This picture showing Hyper-V service is also enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeFn4.png)

[This picture is showing the installer has been stuck at "Removing Files.." stage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfi3o.png)

A little help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Some basic questions: Do you run the installer as an admin? Could there be some other process accessing the install directory? If you close the installer are the files present in your Start directory?

Comment: 1. Yes, I am executing the installer with administrative privilege.
2. No other program or process blocks the installer directory.
3. I don’t know where the installer extracting/unpacking the files.

Comment: The files has been extracted in the "Program Files" directory and all the files are present after closing the installer

Comment: Do you have start entries for Docker?

Comment: Have the same issues on installation/update.
Do you get any workaround for this?

Comment: Sandip, do you mind accepting the answer so it no longer shows as an unanswered question?  It also seems to be helping people as it's received five upvotes!  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Finally** - I was able to upgrade - and I believe this was/is related to all of your issues as well.  Basically I had docker working.  After a couple months of seeing the upgrade docker pop-up, I clicked it.  It broke the installation and with great pain I was able to roll back and install the original version I had.  I then foolishly went to upgrade docker again as I was having an issue with some images not working properly - doh, broke the docker again.  I tried reinstalling three times and it would always get stuck at removing files.  Googling around, someone mentioned are the files actually there.  They were indeed there in `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker` so I tried to run docker manually, it runs but shows red in system tray and states "Backend service is not installed".

I tried to find out how to install the Backend Service but that didnt work.  I tried to install a couple more times, still no luck so what I believe fixed everything is:
 1.  Delete the Docker directory, if you get an error that some process is still using something in that directory make sure you dont have any other folder or files open within that directory.  Make sure docker is stopped, e.g. right click the icon in the system tray and select quit docker.
 2. After deletion - simply reinstall Docker.

**Warning** - this will definitely cause you to likely lose some of your settings so if anyone would like to comment as to which files might be backed up prior please fell free to do so!

Hopefully this might help others out.

Comment: Thanks ! Removing `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker` and `%programdata%\docker` helped in my case.
More context about his issue on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1172

Comment: Glad the answers helped someone else! Thanks for the link with more info!

Comment: Deleting `%programdata%\docker` fixed the issue for me. Not sure it was related but I also disabled HIPS protection from ESET Nod 32 and the real time protection during the installation.

Comment: I had the same problem after not using Docker for a few months, following the temptation to upgrade, foolishly thinking that the upgrade would work better than what I had working 3 months ago.  Docker is very bad about software quality assurance, especially for the unsupported "Community Edition".  They forget to do simple stuff like removing the space in the name of the "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" file, causing it to fail when run from the command line.   I ran the unstaller, and then deleted all files in %programdata%\docker, and then rebooted.  Luckily it preserved my settings!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, btw, I was installing Docker for the first time on my Win 10 pro machine. The culprit was

> Controlled folder access

Windows new feature Controlled Folder Access for Ransomware protection was turned on and which was not allowing docker to create a short cut on desktop. After turning Controlled folder access 'off', I was able to install the docker. I think by unchecking 'create desktop shortcut' while installing docker should cause no problem as well, however, I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answer, I've seen people suggest a computer restart, running the installer as administrator and disabling the antivirus as well.

Answer (score -2):

If Docker is not installing on our pc, first update your pc and then try command to install Docker on your pc , I am sure that it will work. It is because of your OS Build number is small as compared to number for installing Docker. So by updating your pc , Build number will automatically increase. Before updating your pc, check your Build number by gong on Winver,and after updating your pc check your Build number.

Comment: This doesn't add any additional helpful information. Please be sure that when answering a question you're adding something useful vs. duplicating what someone else has already said.

Comment: Ok sir Thank you